# Построить очередь, удалить из неё слова начинающиеся на букву c#

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Такое задание -  Построить очередь из фамилий. Удалить из неё фамилии, что начинаются на букву "А".
Попытался реализовать следующую логику - заполнение очереди через лист, затем перезапись в другой лист во время которой происходит проверка на первую букву, далее инициализация той же очереди из отсортированного списка. Всё работает, но логика немного мудрёная, можно ли сделать как-то проще?

```
public static void StartSurnameA()
        {
            var employees = new List<string> { "Андрианов", "Фомин", "Яковлев", "Сёмин", "Софронов", 
                "Александров", "Иванов", "Андреев", "Захаров", };
            Queue<string> peoples = new Queue<string>(employees);
            foreach (var pers in peoples) Console.Write(pers + " ");
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach(var x in peoples)
            {
                if (!(x.StartsWith("А")))
                {
                    list.Add(x);
                }
            }
            peoples.Clear();
            peoples = new Queue<string>(list);
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var pers in peoples) Console.Write(pers + " ");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.StartSurnameA();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: зачем вам вообще list? Если делаете вторую структуру данных - так берите сразу очередь. Читайте их первой очереди и пишите во вторую. Хотя ортимальней конечно писать в ту же очередь, как советуют в ответе ниже

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так - определяете размер очереди n  и делаете n операций:

- взяли элемент из начала очереди
- если он не начинается на нужную букву, то вставили в конец этой же очереди.

Всё.

Псевдокод

```
n = peoples.Count;
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
   s = peoples.Dequeue();
   if (s[0] != 'A') 
       peoples.Enqueue(s);
}
```

Comment: Да, так будет правильнее. Не подскажете как это в коде реализовать?)

Comment: Но это же элементарные операции с очередью. Набросал.

Comment: @wavy_ - MBo, не забывайте тегать собеседника

Comment: @aepot В данном случае извещения и так будут

Comment: Не будут, автоизвещения собеседникам есть только под вопросом и то только для нескольких начальных комментов, во всех остальных случаях автоизвещения идут только автору текущего поста (вопроса или ответа).

Comment: @wavy_ Я вижу, вы ни одного ответа не приняли. В курсе про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer ?